# Align P elements vertically in separate floated divs

Tags: css, html, css-float, alignment

I have 3 floated divs, all 3 of them have two child **p** elements with texts (one with description, one with a url).

The description can be any length and therefore must be dynamic. The links go below them. I would like to align the links vertically one to each other so their "y position" would be basically the same. I am unable to achieve this as if one of the descriptions is longer (occupies more lines) than the other ones, its link is of course lower than the links of the other divs. I am not quite sure whether I am making myself clear but here is the code and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rb9aa/), should be obvious from that:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="floated">
        <p class="desc">This is some description</p>
        <p class="link">This is a link</p>
    </div>
    <div class="floated">
        <p class="desc">This is some description that is really long, bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
        <p class="link">This is a link</p>
    </div>
    <div class="floated">
        <p class="desc">This is some description which is just long enough not to fit to one line.</p>
        <p class="link">This is a link that is longer than the other ones and does not fit onto one line</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* So all the floated elements have the same height */
}
.floated {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 500px; /* So all the floated elements have the same height */
    margin-bottom: -500px; /* So all the floated elements have the same height */
}
.desc {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: center;
    text-align-last: center;
}

.link {
    color: #e31500;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

As you can see the all of the links have different vertical positions. I would like to achieve that all of them would have the same position as the lowest one, in this case column 2. Is it even possible without changing the HTML? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about the long link?

Comment: The long link should behave exactly the same: its first line should be vertically aligned with the other 2 links.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your HTML markup...
go for it using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EDoCUJUR/4/edit)***

```
#container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:table;       /* tada! */
  position:relative;
  background:#eee;
}
.floated {
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;  /* tada! */
  width: 300px; 
  padding-bottom:45px; /* note this */
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: center;
  text-align-last: center;
  background:#ddd;
}
.desc{ }
.link{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  bottom:0px;
  width:33%;           /* this */
  height:45px;         /* and this */
  color: #e31500;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

the only bad thing is that you'll have to set some height for the `.link` otherwise you should completely modify your HTML and the easiest way would be using `table` structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your mark-up you can add the following css lines of code,which is not acceptable,since the content may vary.

```
.desc{
    height:100px;    
}
```

now if you wish to change your mark-up

the following is the html mark-up.

```
<div id="container">
<div class="floated">
    <p class="desc">This is some description</p>
</div>
<div class="floated">
    <p class="desc">This is some description that is really long, bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>
<div class="floated">
    <p class="desc">This is some description which is just long enough not to fit to one line.</p>
</div>
<div class="floated links">
    <p class="link">This is a link</p>
</div>
<div class="floated">
    <p class="link">This is a link</p>
</div>
<div class="floated">
    <p class="link">This is a link that is longer than the other ones and does not fit onto one line</p>
</div>
```

add the following css along with your code.
    .links{
      clear:both;
      float:left;
    }